# How to determine if a set of vectors forms a basis for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$U = \{(x, y, z, w)\in R^4 | x - 2y = z+w\}$

$S = \{(1, 0, 1, 0), (2, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1)\}$

Determine if S is a basis for U.

I started by showing that S is linearly independent. I made a matrix where each vector in S was a column. I found that the only solutions for $a(1, 0, 1, 0) + b(2, 1, 0, 0) + c(1, 0, 0, 1) = 0$ were $a, b, c = 0$.

Now that I know S is linearly independent, how do I show that it is or isn't a basis of U? I checked and know that every vector in S is in U.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $S$ to be a basis, it must be linearly independent and span $U$.

As you noted, linear independence can be checked by computing the kernel of the matrix.

To check if $S$ spans $U$, let $\vec{u}$ be an arbitrary vector in $U$ and show that $\vec{u}\in\text{span}(S)$.

To this end, a general vector of $U$ is of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2y+z+w \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{bmatrix}.$$ So we want to find $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix}2y+z+w \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

To do this, try and check which vectors on the right-hand side contain nonzero entries which are zero for the other two vectors. For example, the first vector contains a $1$ in the third row, whereas all the other vectors have zero in the third row! Because of this, we know that $a$ equals $z$.

Keep doing this process. Eventually, you'll either find $a,b,c$ that satisfy this, or you'll be able to make up a counterexample! (In this case such $a,b,c$ making this equation hold exist, so there is no counterexample!)

Then since $S$ is linearly independent and spans $U$, $S$ is a basis for $U$!

Comment: So because we can change every entry for the vector on the left to be a combination of the constants and variables on the right we know that the vectors on the right span the subspace?

Comment: View it as a game. An opponent hands you the vector on the left, and you need to get it as a linear combination of vectors on the right. This means that for *any* $y$, $z$, and $w$ that your opponent chooses, your choice of $a$, $b$, and $c$ should yield the equality above. Because of this, you want to allow $a$, $b$, and $c$ to depend on $y$, $z$, $w$. That is, $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be expressions involving real numbers and $y$, $z$, and $w$. 

In general, finding such $a$, $b$, $c$ can be hard. But these vectors have many zeros, so use the hint described above!

Comment: In general problems like these, it could be the case that no such $a$, $b$, $c$ exist! In that case, you should explain why no such $a$, $b$, $c$ could exist. For example, you could substitute a specific value for the variables (in our case $y$, $z$, and $w$) and from this substitution give an argument why no such $a$, $b$, $c$ can exist.

But again, you don't have to worry about that for this problem! In this problem there are such $a$, $b$, $c$. I explained how to figure out that $a=z$. Try to find out what $b$ and $c$ are!

Comment: so $ b = y, a = z $ and $c = w $ Then $ 2y + z + w = 2b + a + c $ so S is a basis for U because we're able to represent all of the values with a combination of values from the right.

Comment: You're correct!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do the opposite: to check if every vector in U is in S.

Hint: note that every vector in U can be written as
$$(2y+z+w, y, z, w) = y(2,1,0,0) +z(1,0,1,0) +w(1,0,0,1)$$